# Decryption failed when storing the key inside Java key store

Tags: encryption, keystore

I've created an encryption key by the following code:

```
SecretKeyFactory skFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWithSHA1AndDESede");
SecretKey key = skFactory.generateSecret(new PBEKeySpec("<some password>".toCharArray()));
```

Then I've used the key to encrypt some text.

I've stored this key inside a java key store and saved in on FS:

```
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JCEKS");
ks.setKeyEntry(keyAlias, key ,keyPassword.toCharArray(), null);
FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream (keyStorePath);
keyStore.store(fileOutputStream , keyStorePassword.toCharArray());
fileOutputStream.close();
```

In a different process I open the key store and try to decrypt some text:

```
KeyStore ks2 = KeyStore.getInstance("JCEKS");
ks2.load(new java.io.FileInputStream(keyStorePath), ksPassword.toCharArray());
SecretKeyFactory skFactory2 = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWithSHA1AndDESede");
String passForTheKey = ks2.getKey(keyAlias, keyPass.toCharArray()).toString();
KeySpec key = new PBEKeySpec(passForTheKey.toCharArray());
SecretKey sKey2 = skFactory.generateSecret(key);
```

When trying to decrypt the text I get the error:

```
java.security.InvalidKeyException: Given final block not properly padded
```

If I try to use the key without storing it in the key store immediately after creating it, the decription proccess is working great.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're storing the actual secret key in your keystore (which is normal). However, you seem to be trying to read it as a password, for a new key you're generating later.

Instead of this:

```
String passForTheKey = ks2.getKey(keyAlias, keyPass.toCharArray()).toString();
KeySpec key = new PBEKeySpec(passForTheKey.toCharArray());
SecretKey sKey2 = skFactory.generateSecret(key);
```

use this:

```
SecretKey sKey2 = (SecretKey) ks2.getKey(keyAlias, keyPassword.toCharArray());
```

What you're reading from the keystore is the key itself (as you've stored it), not some password. (`generateSecret` will just generate a new key.)